# Numpy Adding two vectors with different sizes

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

If I have two numpy arrays of different sizes, how can I superimpose them.

```
a = numpy([0, 10, 20, 30])
b = numpy([20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70])
```

What is the cleanest way to add these two vectors to produce a new vector (20, 40, 60, 80, 60, 70)?

This is my generic question. For background, I am specifically applying a Green's transform function and need to superimpose the results for each time step in the evaulation unto the responses previously accumulated.

Comment: Just a curiosity, why do you prefer creating a new vector instead of using a single (always the same) target vector to superimpose each iteration? I think this could be more memory efficient.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This could be what you are looking for

```
if len(a) < len(b):
    c = b.copy()
    c[:len(a)] += a
else:
    c = a.copy()
    c[:len(b)] += b
```

basically you copy the longer one and then add in-place the shorter one

Comment: How to do it if the arrays are inside an array ?

Comment: What do you mean with "inside an array"? if you want a new fresh array when the sum the code stays the same, if instead you want to do the addition in-place then just work on the appropriate slice (e.g. `m[i][j][:len(a)] += a`).

Answer (score 17):

If you know that `b` is higher dimension, then:

```
>>> a.resize(b.shape)
>>> c = a+b
```

is all you need.

Comment: That will only work if there is no other reference to `a`. and many times there are internal references, you don't know of.

Answer (score 3):

Very similar to the one above, but a little more compact:

```
l = sorted((a, b), key=len)
c = l[1].copy()
c[:len(l[0])] += l[0]
```